# Template for container and container content type C++

Tags: c++, templates, containers

I essentially want

```
template <typename Container, typename T>
void copy(Container<T> &A, const Container<T> &B)
{
   (copy contents from B to A) ...
}
```

But afaik, it cannot be done this way. Usage wise, it would copy contents from (example) `vector<int> A, B`, but also work for `list<float> A, B`, for instance.

So the single function would work for containers of different types and different data types for their respective containers.

Comment: Side note: if you make a generic iterator interface you can have a function that doesn't care what the container is. [See C++'s own `std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) for an example of this, including a few sample implementations you can gleefully steal ideas from.

Comment: Sidenote: In the C++ standard library, the order of arguments is the other way around, so your function is likely going to cause some confusion among users. I suggest copying from the first into the second. `A -> B`.

Comment: @EthanR, my pitch would change how the function looks to something like `void copy(iterator from_start, iterator from_end, iterator to_start)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make `Container` a [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters):

```
template <template<typename...> typename Container, typename T>
Container<T> copy(Container<T> A, Container<T> B)
{
   // (copy contents from B to A) ...
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could simply write:

```
template <typename Container>
Container copy(Container A, Container B)
{
   // (copy contents from B to A) ...
}
```

if you don't need to explicitly name the element type `T`. You can still get this type by doing `Container::value_type` anyway.

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind this? Or is there a specific article that talks about this? I'd like to understand why I need to do it this way, seeing as it syntactically doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I added a link, there are examples there. Basically, you need to say `Container<T>` and you can only do that if `Container` is itself a template.

Comment: Thank you! And I edited the original post. I realize it returns void, not a container.

Comment: @EthanR No problem. Normally you shouldn't edit the question after an answer has been posted, but it's ok this time, since that part was not really relevant to your question.